# Using Wildcards or RegEx to Display Files Based on Filename in PHP

Tags: php, regex, wildcard

I want to display images based on the characters of a 15 digit filename. My first thought was to use wildcards but now I'm thinking RegEx may be more appropriate. However I don't know how to incorporate RegEx into the `glob()` function.

I want the first digit to be 9 and the 12th and 13th digits to be 0s. Here's kinda what I want to do.

```
foreach (glob("./dir/9**********00**.png") as $file) {
    echo "<img src='$file'>";
}
```

I'm sure this is really simple but I wasn't able to find how to do it in my searches. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `*` is the placeholder for an arbitrary number of characters, while `?` stands for a single one. See [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) and [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch).

Comment: Yep....as easy as I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a regex for that, you can use: `9\d{10}00\d{2}`